Enable TLS communication for k8s application problem
Deployment.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wc-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wc
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wc
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: wc
        image: myrepo33/wc:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4499

Service.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wc-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: wc
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 4499
      nodePort: 30001
  type: NodePort

Task
● The app must be exposed as a Kubernetes service for
accessibility.
●Ensure that the application supports secure TLS
communication.
Now to access app on internet, I tried nodePort but not working. I am working in Minikube.
As you can see in service file i exposed nodePort 30001 so i opened port from Security Group as well still not working. Locally by using curl it is working.
And the second task is app should support TLS communication which i don't know ho to do that.

If you're not doing TLS termination via an Ingress service or cloud-provider-specific settings in a LoadBalancer, there's not anything else in Kubernetes that would help you set it up.  You'd need to provide your own certificates, and the way you configure them would be specific to the application you're running.

I don't have my own domain so how can I provide my own certs.
